# Looping through class objects to find an object with certain attributes in python

Tags: python, loops, class, object

I am trying to find a way to loop through the different skills for my game my code is below

```
class Skill:
  def __init__(self, user, desc, effect, ea, amount, am):
    self.user = user
    self.desc = desc
    self.effect = effect
    self.amount = amount
    self.am = am

s1 = Skill("user1", "lightning blade", "Decrease", "health", 165419, 34743)
s2 = Skill("user1", "hurricane dash", "Decrease", "Speed", 113479, 95791)
s3 = Skill("user2", "earthquake", "Increase", "attack", 163479, 35791)

#want to loop through class object to auto find "lightning blade" skill
```

the objective is to print / use the skill object with `desc` attribute as 'lightning blade' from the list of objects above ignoring the "hurricane dash" from the same user and user2's skill "earthquake" when "lightning blade" is found I also want to get the `amount` and `am` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the skill objects are dynamic or real time, you can code it as shown below:

```
class Skill:
  skill_objs = []
  # variables like 'skill_objs' are called class variables that are common among all the objects of a particular class
  def __init__(self, user, desc, effect, ea, amount, am):
    self.user = user
    self.desc = desc
    self.effect = effect
    self.amount = amount
    self.am = am
    # 'self' here refers to the current object
    Skill.skill_objs.append(self)

s1 = Skill("user1", "lightning blade", "Decrease", "health", 165419, 34743)
s2 = Skill("user1", "hurricane dash", "Decrease", "Speed", 113479, 95791)
s3 = Skill("user2", "earthquake", "Increase", "attack", 163479, 35791)

wanted_skill_obj = None
# class variables can be accessed using the syntax <class_name>.<variable_name> like 'Skill.skill_objs'
for skill in Skill.skill_objs:
   if(skill.desc == 'lightning blade'):
      wanted_skill_obj = skill
      break;
# to get the attributes of the wanted skill
if(wanted_skill_obj == None):
   print("No skill found!")
else:
   print('desc: ',wanted_skill_obj.desc)
   print('Amount: ', wanted_skill_obj.amount)
   print('am: ', wanted_skill_obj.am)
```

Comment: is there a way to code it so that it auto adds the skill as I add to the class?

Comment: Yeah, you can code that functionality in the constructor i.e., `__init()__`. One way to do it is to create a list of class type, basically a class variable so that you can access it by class name, and in the constructor, you can add code to add the current object to that list, so that, whenever you create an object, contructor method is called, which automatically adds the current object to list. If you don't get it, let me know by a comment, so that I can edit my answer with updated code.

Comment: I don't get it, please demonstrate, thank you for the kind help!

Comment: I have added a full version of working code, let me know if you are unclear about anything. For more clarity, you can read some material on internet about constructors, class data members vs instance data members, class variables vs object variables and other OOP concepts.